# Delphi, chromium, tabs and flash trouble

Tags: delphi, chromium, delphi-xe3, chromium-embedded

So I have this project in which I need to have few tabs (TPageControl) with flash pages running and grab a screenshot of them from time to time without switching active tab.
First I tried TChromiumOSR but the flash is not visible in it, kind of works if I click on a page's button that opens a popup with flash maximized. so it doesn't look like a problem with flash but rather with frames or sth. anywas a no-go.

then I've tried TChromium, everything works alright but I don't know how to grab a screenshot of a control that is on non-active TTabSheet without switching tabs.

using latest dcef3 trunk

any ideas? thanks

edit: It turned out that flash not being visible in OSR is an old chromium bug. It's actually playing but not visible if embedding code has "wmode" set to something else than 'transparent'. I've managed to change that property through js. To actually see the change, flash object needs to be removed from DOM and added again:

```
  chr1.browser.GetFrame(str[i]).ExecuteJavaScript('document.getElementsByName("wmode")[0].value="transparent";', '', 0);
  chr1.browser.GetFrame(str[i]).ExecuteJavaScript('document.getElementsByName("wmode")[1].value="transparent";', '', 0);
  chr1.browser.GetFrame(str[i]).ExecuteJavaScript('var wtf = document.getElementById("gameApp2");', '', 0);
  chr1.browser.GetFrame(str[i]).ExecuteJavaScript('document.getElementById("gameApp2").remove();', '', 0);
  chr1.browser.GetFrame(str[i]).ExecuteJavaScript('document.body.appendChild(wtf);', '', 0);
```

Comment: I see there is a Type Library "Shockwave Flash", would it work if you let Delphi create an ActiveX wrapper around that and put that on your form?

Comment: not really, I'm automating a flash game and it needs to be run as a webpage with all the cookies and stuff

Comment: Have you tried TWebBrowser? I've had success grabbing snapshots from it before using OleDraw: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692711(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I used it before but it lacked ability to automate mouse and keyboard and it's not as portable as chromium. looks like i'm good with osr working finally

Answer (score 0):

If the tab is not being shown (it's not the front one), it doesn't get drawn (this is an operating system thing). If it's not being drawn, there's nothing there for a screenshot to capture.

If your requirement is to capture a Flash page without it being displayed, you're going to have to find another way to do it.

Comment: still i'm hoping to achieve this with off screen rendering mode as browser uses TPaintBox32's canvas and should be calling 'paint' regardless of control being visible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Chrome is still based on WebKit, I know WebKitGTK has its own snapshot engine, if it carries down deep enough, perhaps you can tap into that for your captures.

At one point, there was a behavioural issue with TPageControl that until a tab had been selected, none of its children had valid handles created.  I do not know if that is still the case, but if it is, it may complicate your desire to not switch tabs.

Assuming the control HAS a valid window handle, you might create a TBITMAP, lock its canvas, grab the Canvas's handle (DC) and fake a WM_PAINT to the control to get it to render to your bitmap.

Comment: I can grab the canvas/bitmap of control to which TChromiumOSR paints now when it's fixed. thanks anyways